# Calculation of $\int_{0}^1 \frac{\sin(\ln^4(1-x))}{x}~dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(\ln^4 (1-x))}{x}dx$$

What is the closed-form evaluation of this integral?

I honestly do not have a single clue how to solve this.

(There is no application, but it is out of curiosity.)

Comment: I doubt that a closed form could be expected. Numerical methods are probably the only way. By the way, did you plot the integrand ?

Comment: In this case, does $ln^4(1-x)$ mean $(ln(1-x))^4$ or does it mean $ln(ln(ln(ln(x))))$?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have plotted it.

Comment: @ASKASK the former.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I believe that this has a closed form because there are lots of closed form solutions to problems that are widely believed to have none...

Comment: Usually when the integral of something with $\sin x$ has a closed form it is when the same thing but with $e^{ix}$ has closed form via contour integrals, but the latter does not converge.

Comment: @0.5772156649... Is you user name the approximate value of $$\frac{1}{2} \sqrt[6]{e} \sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi }}$$

Comment: I don't have a closed form, but this may be useful: $I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^4 x}{e^x-1}\,dx\approx0.2450351412057$.

Comment: @ChrisCulter I think you meant $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin (x^4)}{e^x-1}\,dx$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No, it is $\gamma$

Comment: @0.5772156649...Oooops !!

Comment: @OlivierOloa Oh right, I don't know why I wrote that! Anyway, the $0.2450351412057\ldots$ is correct.